# phpDoc, Yii 1.x and generating packages

Tags: yii, package, phpdoc

I have a problem dealing with phpdoc
I need to generate phpdoc for big project based on Yii 1.x, the problem is it's not go with namespaces. Generating phpdoc gives me whole project located on "/" level
I need to save project's folder structure.

@package doesn't work here. Is there any option to force phpdoc in a such way?

Answer (score 1):

If your code uses namespaces, you need phpDocumentor 2.x (www.phpdoc.org).  The old 1.x version at PEAR (pear.php.net) does not recognize namespacing.

Comment: I don't need namespaces but i need to organize structure by folders... Is there any way to get this?

Comment: Using @package is the only "organizing" mechanism available aside from namespaces.

Comment: If @package tags in your class docblocks are not causing phpDocumentor to group your classes together, then that's a *serious* bug.  I suggest opening at issue on it (https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues?state=open).  Just a sample code piece of two empty classes with docblocks should be enough to demonstrate it.